# Proof of no rational point on Selmer's Curve $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, examples

The projective curve $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$ is often cited as an example (given by Selmer) of a **failure of the [Hasse Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle)**: the equation has solutions in any completion of the rationals $\mathbb Q$, but not in $\mathbb Q$ itself.

I don't think I've ever seen a proof of the latter claim — is someone able to provide an outline? What are the necessary tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My friend has written an introduction to algebraic number theory before, which contains a short proof of this statement, but I didn't check its validity.

**Edit:** updated the link of the document, http://www.2shared.com/document/2d6M7kNU/Introduction_to_Algebraic_Numb.html
p. 41 of the document, or p. 45 of the PDF.

Comment: This is certainly a lot more elementary than the other methods mentioned, although it (therefore) does not present a clear example of what the general obstruction is (for the failure of Hasse). Still, thanks a lot - at least this is a proof I can easily follow :-)


Comment: For what it's worth, I once worked out a completely elementary proof that the equation has p-adic solutions for all p and put it on an UG example sheet here:  http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/teaching/04Lent/M4P32/exsht3.pdf

Comment: The link in the answer is now broken.

Comment: @Ho Chung Siu, do you happen to have a copy of that paper anywhere accessible? 

Comment: Hi, the link is updated.

Comment: I think the link is broken again :(

Answer (score 10):

This problem is in Cassels' book "Local Fields" and I wrote up a solution once along those lines, for an algebraic number theory class. See [this paper](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf), but I should advise that it comes out seeming pretty tedious.  Solutions that involve elliptic curves are more conceptual.  Others have already provided pointers to references for that approach.

Comment: Ten years too late, but I thought I'd point it out: the section headings in this paper are flipped! You wrote "No local solutions" and then "Global solutions". Regardless, thank you for this, and your numerous other awesome papers.

Comment: @AlonAmit fixed.  You can email me directly the next time you find a typo.

Answer (score 6):

I think I saw a proof of that in Cassel's "Diophantine Equations with special reference to elliptic curves" and in some surveys by Mazur in the Bull. AMS (perhaps [this](http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/mazur2.pdf), but I have in the moment no time to look).

Comment: Interesting. The obstruction, as presented by Mazur, is that the curve 60x^3+y^3+z^3=0 *does* have a rational point, and is a "companion" (Q-twist of) the Selmer curve. I'll need to dig a lot more to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: "This" is now dead, but it appears to have been a link to [Mazur - On the passage from local to global in number theory](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1993-29-01/S0273-0979-1993-00414-2), with the relevant result beginning on p. 22.

Answer (score 6):

There's a proof in Cassels' little blue book on elliptic curves which the OP might find more to his taste than some others mentioned here.

Answer (score 5):

The "standard" technique for killing the Hasse priniciple for elliptic curves is to show that the Tate-Shafarevich group has a copy of (Z/mZ)^2 for some m - see chapter X in Silverman's the arithmetic of Eliptic curves, both for the theory and examples. All the examples which Silverman presents ar with m = 2. Selmers example requires m = 3, which requires (much) more computations. Poonen has an [example](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/cubics.ps)
on his web page of a family of elliptic curves violating the Hasse principle, and containing Selmers example, but you'd have to dive through a labirinth of references.

Comment: (Hello there :-) ) That's pretty heavy machinery for this humble reader - but an interesting view of the obstruction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: (Hello indeed :) ) The advantage this approach has is certainly not simplicity, it is rather that it can be - and is - mechanised. Google up Hasse Tate Shafarevich and Magma.