# Diophantine equation with no integer solutions, but with solutions modulo every integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, reference-request

It's probably common knowledge that there are Diophantine equations which do not admit any solutions in the integers, but which admit solutions modulo $n$ for every $n$. This fact is stated, for example, in Dummit and Foote (p. 246 of the 3rd edition), where it is also claimed that an example is given by the equation
$$ 3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0. $$
However, D&F say that it's "extremely hard to verify" that this equation has the desired property, and no reference is given as to where one can find such a verification.

So my question is: Does anyone know of a readable reference that proves this claim (either for the above equation or for others)? I haven't had much luck finding one.

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2779/proof-of-no-rational-point-on-selmers-curve-3x34y35z30

Comment: But this equation has a solution $(0,0,0)$. 

Comment: @Fedor: "solution" here refers to a point on the corresponding projective curve.

Comment: The example in your question is a famous example of Selmer.   An explanation is given by Keith Conrad here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf


Note also that the example given below by Qiaochu are reducible. One can show that if $f(x)$ is an integer polynomial in one variable that is irreducible, then it cannot have a solution modulo every prime.  The essential point of Selmer's example is that it is irreducible.

Comment: Qiaochu & Emerton: Thanks! I'm glad to learn that this curve has a name.

Comment: A proof that there are no solutions over Q is in Cassels' book on elliptic curves. An elementary proof that there are p-adic solutions for all p, using Hensel's lemma and an argument very much in the spirit of Qiaochu's answer (i.e. using a "cube" analogue of the statement that if $a$ and $b$ aren't squares mod $p$ then $ab$ is) can be found at http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/teaching/10Aut/M4P32/exsht3.pdf : I just set it as homework for my students in fact :-)



Comment: Remark: the reason I'm blowing my own trumpet here is that Keith's pdf resorts to the crutch of showing there are solutions mod p by using character sums over finite fields; this is often the approach used, in my experience. The homework I set gives a self-contained approach inspired by the trick used in the quadratic case.

Comment: PS *gah* why didn't I follow Qiaochu's duplicate link before posting all that stuff again :-/

Comment: Is Emerton's assertion easy to prove? (that an irreducible polynomial in one variable cannot have a root modulo every prime). The easy case is the one where the polynomial gives a Galois extension. Then Tchebotarev density thm implies the result, but if the extension is not Galois, taking the Galois closure is not enough... (I guess that the result should say that it cannot have a solution on a set of primes with density 1).

Comment: Dear A. Pacetti, Here is the argument I had in mind (it is not original to me, though); hopefully I am not butchering it:
consider the Galois group $G$ of the splitting field of the polynomial.  If the poly. $f$ is irred., then $G$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$, and so group theory shows that (if $f$ has degree $> 1$) then there is a conjugacy of $G$ with no fixed point.  The $p$ whose Frobenius elements are equal to this conjugacy class then have the property that $f$ has no root modulo $p$.  (Such a root would give a fixed point for the Frobenius of $p$.  

Comment: Sorry: "conjugacy of $G$" should read "conjugacy class of $G$".

Comment: Another elementary example is $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=-1$. Because every positive integer is a sum of 4 squares, this has solutions modulo every $n\ge 2$.

Comment: See this [previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2779) for a more specific discussion of proofs of the properties of Selmer’s curve.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is actually quite straightforward to write down examples in one variable where this occurs.  For example, the Diophantine equation $(x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3)(x^2 - 6) = 0$ has this property: for any prime $p$, at least one of $2, 3, 6$ must be a quadratic residue, so there is a solution $\bmod p$, and by Hensel's lemma (which has to be applied slightly differently when $p = 2$) there is a solution $\bmod p^n$ for any $n$.  We conclude by CRT.  (**Edit:**  As Fedor says, there are problems at $2$.  We can correct this by using, for example, $(x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 17)(x^2 - 34)$.)

Hilbert wrote down a family of quartics with the same property.  There are no (monic) cubics or quadratics with this property: if a monic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg f \le 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ (which is equivalent to not having an integer solution), then by the Frobenius density theorem there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f(x)$ is irreducible $\bmod p$.

Comment: @Qiaochu : CRT ?

Comment: I am afraid that this specific example does not have solution modulo 8, but if one multiples by $(x^2-17)$ then it becomes ok.

Comment: @Andres: Chinese remainder theorem.  @Fedor: oops!  I think there is a simpler example along those lines, though.

Comment: Qiaochu: Out of curiosity, what is Hilbert's family of examples?

Comment: I approve ! I gave the same example $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)=0$ thirty-three years ago, at the oral examination of the French teaching contest "Agrégation".

Answer (score 38):

Here is another example, which is easy to verify by hand: $x^2+23y^2=41$. Note it has rational solutions (e.g. $(1/3,4/3)$). This provides solutions modulo $m$ if $(m,3)=1$.
For $m$ a power of $3$, there is always a solution with $x=0$. Verifying that it doesn't have integral solutions is trivial.

Comment: The example I usually give my students is $x^2-37y^2=3$. The rational solution is $7/2,1/2$ and there's a 2-adic integer solution as well. However it's much harder to prove there's no integer solutions! (I can do it without too much trouble on a computer but...) So I'm very grateful for your example Felipe!

Comment: An easy way to see that there are $3$-adic solutions is to note that $(81/13, 4/13)$ is a solution.

Comment: $(9/4,5/4)$ is a solution too. I should have looked for other rational solutions.

Answer (score 21):

The equation 2x^2 + 7y^2 = 1 has two rational solutions with small relatively prime denominators (hence as a congruence mod m it is solvable for all m by CRT) but it visibly has no integral solutions. Look for a rational solution with denominator 3 and also for one with denominator 5 (small numerators in both cases).

Comment: KConrad: it would have been shorter to say "$(1/3,1/3)$ and $(3/5,1/5)$" than "Look for a rational solution....both cases)." :-)

Comment: Yours seems to me like the "best" answer so far though (simplest equation, smallest coefficients).

Comment: A Weierstrass equation in this spirit is y^2 = x^3 - 51 (which BCnrd told me about, and I think he got it from Venkatesh). It has the rational solution (1375/9,50986/27) and it can be solved mod 3^r for any r using x = 1 and for y a square root of -50 mod 3^r (which exists since -50 = 1 mod 3). Thus as a congruence this equation has a  solution mod m for any m. That there is no Z-solution follows from Q(sqrt(-51)) having class number 2, which is rel. prime to 3, by the same kind of method used to find the Z-solutions to y^2 = x^3-2.

Comment: The point of my previous comment was to have a rational point and no integral point, but the rational point doesn't matter.  For many nonzero integers $k$ (e.g., $k = \pm 6$) the equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$ has no integral solutions, but for *every* nonzero integer $k$, the congruence $y^2 \equiv x^3 + k \bmod m$ has a solution for all $m \geq 2$. It suffices by Chinese remainder theorem to show there is a solution when $m$ runs through prime powers, and my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134352/ does that. (At https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875983/ I show solns mod $p$.)

Comment: A simpler example than $y^2 = x^3 - 51$ of such an equation with no integral solution and with a rational solution is $y^2 = x^3 + 11$, with rational solution $(-7/4,19/8)$.  That it has no integral solution can be proved with just congruences and knowing when $-1 \equiv \Box \bmod p$, no need for class numbers.  See Theorem 2.3 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf.  The rational solution shows there is a solution mod $p^r$ for odd primes $p$, and to get a solution mod powers of $2$ there is a $2$-adic solution $(x,2)$ where $x^3 = -7$ with $x \equiv 1 \bmod 2$.

Answer (score 19):

Consider the equation $(2x - 1)(3x - 1) = 0$.  This equation has no integer solutions.  But modulo $n$, it always has a solution.  If $n$ is not a multiple of $2$, we can make $2x -1$ a multiple of $n$.  If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, we can make $3x - 1$ a multiple of $n$.  Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can handle every other $n$ by piecing together these two solutions.

Answer (score 8):

There is an  easier example in

http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Experimental_1995.pdf

where Kap disposed of the concern with the brief "(it is easy to see that the assumption of no congruence obstructions is satisfied)."

The example is, given a positive prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is no solution in integers $x,y,z$ to
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^9 = 216 p^3  $$

Robert C. Vaughan wrote to Kap (prior to publication) in appreciation, there was something involved that "could not be detected p-adically." I forget what, it has been years. But we did well, Vaughan got an early draft in time to include the example in the second edition of
*The Hardy-Littlewood Method*.

Later for some reason I looked at negative targets, with the same primes I believe it turned out that there were no integer solutions to
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^9 = -8 p^3.  $$

The significance of the example is not so much as a single Diophantine equation, rather as a Diophantine representation problem in the general vicinity of the Waring problem, but with mixed exponents: given *nonegative* integer variables $x,y,z$ and exponents $a,b,c \geq 2,$ and given the polynomial $f(x,y,z) =x^a + y^b + z^c,$ if $f(x,y,z)$ represents every positive integer $p$-adically and if $$ \frac{1}{a} +  \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} > 1,  $$  does  $f(x,y,z)$ integrally represent all sufficiently large integers? The answer is no for the problem as stated, but the counterexamples depend heavily on factorization, and in the end upon composition of binary forms. As this is also the mechanism underlying the simplest examples of  spinor exceptional integers for positive ternary quadratic forms, it is natural to ask whether there is some relatively easy formalism that adds "factorization obstructions" to the well-studied "congruence obstructions."

See:

http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Vaughan.pdf

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem)

Comment: Is there a Brauer-Manin obstruction to these examples?

Comment: Hi, Felipe. I really would not know. To be more precise, I do not know what the phrase means. But there is such an example with $x^2 + y^2 + z^n$ where $n$ is any odd and composite number. It is known that $x^2 + y^2 + z^3$ integrally represents all integers, and modest evidence suggests the same for any $n$ odd prime. Meanwhile, warranted or not, I think this is related to my first question in January 2010, $2 x^2 + x y + 3 y^2 + z^3 - z,$ answered with some real effort by Kevin Buzzard. There are about 25 of those, one for each discriminant of positive binary forms with class number 3.

Comment: Felipe, the integral Brauer-Manin obstruction has been systematically invstigated by Colliot-Thélène and Xu (http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~colliot/CTXuCompositio2009.pdf).  $$ $$

Comment: @Chandan: Yes, I know about this paper. My question was whether the lack of integral solutions to Will's examples can be explained by an integral Brauer-Manin obstruction.

Comment: Felipe and Chandan, thank you for at least discussing this a little. Kap's proof by factorization is in the short paper with the link already given in my answer above. The phenomenon, in my comment above, in positive integral ternary quadratic forms is in a 1995 letter by Kap to J. S. Hsia and Rainer Schulze-Pillot, pdf link attempted here:
$$ $$
http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Forms/Kap_Letter_To_Hsia_RSP_1995.pdf 
$$ $$
and the January 2010 question Kevin answered at:
$$  $$
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12486/integers-not-represented-by-2-x2-x-y-3-y2-z3-z 
$$ $$ 
Will
$$ $$  

Answer (score 5):

An example even easier than Jagy and Kaplansky's
$x^2+y^2+z^9 = 216p^3$, for $p=1 \bmod 4$, is given in:

Sums of two squares and one biquadrate, by R. Dietmann, and C. Elsholtz,
Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. Volume 38, Number 2 (2008), 233-234.

http://www.math.tugraz.at/~elsholtz/WWW/papers/papers26de08.pdf

Here we showed:
$x^2+y^2+z^4=p^2$ has no positive solutions, when $p=7 \bmod 8, p $prime. Once the example is known, it's trivial to prove.

The Jagy-Kaplansky example can be generalized to odd composite exponent, instead of 9. It seems the example above was overlooked for quite a while.

Comment: This is nice, Christian.

Answer (score 4):

Let us define the size $H$ of a polynomial Diophantine equation $P(x_1,...,x_n)=0$ as: substitute $2$ instead of all variables, absolute values instead of all coefficients, and evaluate. This notion of size has the advantages that (i) there is a finite number of equations with bounded size, so we can do full computer search and find the smallest equation with any given property and (ii) equations with small $H$ really look nice and compact.

Then the smallest Diophantine equation with no integer solutions, but with solutions modulo every integer is the equation
$$
y(x^2+2)=1
$$
with size $H=2(2^2+2)+1 = 13$.

Proof that a solution exists: As usual for polynomial equations, CRT allows us to reduce to the case $n = p^e$ for $p$ prime and $e$ positive. If $p > 2$, then $p^e$ is odd, so $2$ is invertible mod $p^e$. Set $x = 0, y = 2^{-1}$. If $p = 2$, then $3$ is invertible mod $2^e$. Set $x = 1, y = 3^{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Edited to add a proof. As for the original, I'm not sure what your criterion for "smallest" is; there are plenty of quadratic answers (e.g. see Ravi Boppana's solution for one that's even one-variable). I think you may be restricting yourself to some idea of "fully monic" polynomials.

Comment: I have added explanation in which sense this is the smallest example

Answer (score 3):

See Subsection 6.4.1 in my paper with  Zeev Rudnick [Hardy-Littlewood varieties and semisimple groups, Invent. Math. 119 (1995), 37-66](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01245174), page 62 (or [this PDF file](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Eborovoi/papers/hardy.pdf), page 23).
The equation is:
$$
-9x^2+2xy+7y^2+2z^2=1.
$$
This equation has a rational solution $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1)$, hence it has  solutions modulo $p^n$ for all $p\neq 2$ and all $n$.
In addition, it has a solution $(4,1,1)$ modulo $2^7$, and using Hensel's lemma one can easily check that the equation has solutions modulo $2^n$ for all $n$.
An elementary proof that this equation has no integral solutions is due to Don Zagier and is based on (a supplementary formula to) the quadratic reciprocity law.

Answer (score 2):

The negative Pell equation $x^2-34y^2=-1$ has no integer solutions.

However, it has rational solutions $(x,y)=\left(\pm\frac{5}{3},\pm\frac{1}{3}\right)$ and $(x,y)=\left(\pm\frac{3}{5},\pm\frac{1}{5}\right)$ and since $\gcd(3,5)=1$, it has solutions modulo every integer.

Also, the equation $\binom{x}{2}+3=y^3$ has no integer solutions.

Proof:

Let $t=2x+1$ and $u=2y$.

Then we obtain $x=\frac{t-1}{2}$ and $u=\frac{y}{2}$.

From $\binom{x}{2}+3=y^3$ we get the elliptic curve $$t^2+23=u^3,$$ or $$t^2=u^3-23.$$ The only integer solutions to this equation are $(t,u)=(\pm2,3)$. They do not lead to integer solutions to $$\binom{x}{2}+3=y^3$$ since $t$ must be odd and $u$ must be even. However, this equation has solutions modulo every integer.

The reference for the proof that the equation $3x^3+4y^3=5z^3$ has no nonzero integer solutions but solutions modulo every integer is given by [http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf).