# Is "almost-solvability" of Diophantine equations decidable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, diophantine-equations, decidability

Say that a Diophantine equation is *almost-satisfiable* iff for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it has a solution mod $n$. Trivially genuine satisfiability over $\mathbb{N}$ implies almost-satisfiability, but the converse fails - see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47442/diophantine-equation-with-no-integer-solutions-but-with-solutions-modulo-every), or for a fun "nuke" note that almost-satisfiability is $\Pi^0_1$ and so cannot coincide with satisfiability as the latter is [properly $\Sigma^0_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) *(and as far as I can tell that's actually non-circular! :P)*.

My question is the following: is almost-satisfiability known to be decidable?

It's plausible to me that one could whip up a Diophantine equation $\mathcal{D}_T$ such that the behavior of a given Turing machine $T$ over the first $s$ steps is connected to the behavior of $\mathcal{D}_T$ over  something like $\mathbb{Z}/s\mathbb{Z}$ *(sort of a "Diophantine [Trakhtenbrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trakhtenbrot%27s_theorem)* theorem"), but I don't actually see how to do that. Certainly I don't see how to lift any of the MRDP analysis to almost-satisfiability in a useful way. On the other hand, I also don't see how to get a $\Sigma^0_1$ definition of almost-satisfiability. Work of [Berend/Bilu](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-06/S0002-9939-96-03210-8/S0002-9939-96-03210-8.pdf) shows that almost-satisfiability of single-variable Diophantine equations is decidable, which is nontrivial *(in contrast to genuine solvability for single-variable equations which is a trivial application of the rational roots theorem)*, but at a glance I don't see how to generalize their arguments to multiple variables.

Comment: For what it's worth I suspect almost-satisfiability is decidable, indeed efficiently decidable, but I have no real evidence for that.

Comment: I agree that MRDP analysis won’t help — MRDP uses basic coding like $$\exists x(a=0 \vee b=0) \leftrightarrow \exists x(ab=0)$$ $$\exists x(a=0 \wedge b=0) \leftrightarrow \exists x(a^2+b^2=0)$$ $$\exists x(a\neq 0) \leftrightarrow \exists xy(a=y+1)$$ which all seem to fail if $\exists$ is replaced with almost-existence; I don’t see any almost-replacements for that coding either.

Comment: A perhaps relevant observation is that the common theory of all finite fields is known to be decidable. See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007297000171).

Comment: These slides of Lenstra https://euro-math-soc.eu/system/files/news/Hendrik%20Lenstra_Profinite%20number%20theory.pdf say it's decidable but I didn't see a proof of reference

Comment: Modulo a prime power is not the same as a field of prime power order.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg ... Oof. Not my finest moment. Do "solvable in all finite fields" and "solvable mod every natural" not coincide?

Comment: The case modulo every prime was first proved by Ax in a paper called Solving diophantine problems modulo every prime.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Actually, this paper gives a full answer to the original question: Ax indicates how to prove that “almost solvability” (which is equivalent to solvability over the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ for all primes $p$) is decidable in the paragraph crossing pages 170 and 171 (it is also mentioned in the introduction, see top of p. 162).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I posted it as a CW answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Every finite field contains a prime field, hence “solvable in all finite fields” is the same as “solvable modulo every prime”. This is strictly weaker than “solvable modulo every natural” (which is equivalent to “solvable modulo every prime power”): for example, $x^2+y^2+1=0$ is solvable in all finite fields, but not modulo $4$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What you call "almost-solvability" is called by number theorists "local solvability." More precisely, "local solvability" also includes solvability over the real numbers, which are sometimes referred to as an "archimedean prime" (in contrast to the usual prime numbers, which are "non-archimedean primes"). Situations in which local and global solvability are equivalent are said to satisfy the [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle). The terminology "local" comes from the analogy between number fields and function fields; primes are analogous to points.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thanks, that's useful information!

Comment: @NoahSchweber $x=1$, $y=0$

Comment: @EmilJeřábek ... Welp.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A Diophantine equation is almost-satisfiable iff it is satisfiable over the ring $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$, the profinite completion of $\mathbb Z$ (also called by some the Prüfer ring), by a standard compactness argument (the solutions over each $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ form an inverse system of finite sets whose inverse limit is the set of solutions over $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$, and hence if the set of solutions is non-empty for each $n$, then the inverse limit is non-empty).   From the direct product decomposition $\widehat{\mathbb Z}=\prod_p \mathbb Z_p$, this in turn reduces things to solvability over the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ for all $p$.  This question is solved in the paper J. Ax, Solving diophantine problems modulo every prime. Ann. Math. 85, 161–183 (1967) on pages 170,171.  So the problem is decidable.

Comment: Is this algorithm practical, at least for equations with small coefficients? Is it implemented in any computer algebra system like Mathematica, magma, maple, sagemath, etc? I am aware about Magma function "IsLocallySolvable", but it is about solvability in $Q_p$ rather in $Z_p$. For $Z_p$, we can of course check solvability modulo every prime power up to some bound, but how to compute this bound for the specific equation? Will it be not galactic? If general method is not practical, is there at least a fast method for checking the solvability modulo all powers of the specific prime $p$?

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk, My guess is the proof is not practical given how old it is.  I'm not sure if something better has been proved at least for special classes of equations