# Diophantine oracle $\mathrm{mod}\:p$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose we have an oracle that decides if a given system of polynomial equations with integer coefficients has a solution $\mathrm{mod}\:p$ for every prime $p$.

Can it be decided then if a given system of polynomial equations with integer coefficients has an integer solution?

Comment: No, as the problem of checking if a given system of Diophantine equations has solutions modulo every prime is decidable, see Ax, "Solving Diophantine Problems Modulo Every Prime", 1967.

Comment: ... as is mentioned in https://mathoverflow.net/q/400813 . While that question is a bit different, the answer is effectively the same, hence I’m voting to close as a duplicate.